# Windows Live Writer inconsistent with Media Library

Tags: media-library, windows-live-writer

I'm considering moving my existing blog from DasBlog to WordPress. While doing some tests to see if I did like the platform I ran into following problem:

I'm using Windows Live Writer to write my blog posts. I'm used to add the pictures on the original size and remove the default link (to the full size picture). When I publish this post to WordPress, some pictures end up in the picture library and others don't, even in the same post.

It would be nice to have a consistent way of storing my pictures. Preferably without the use of the media library, as I don't see the use of it (yet?) and it gives [unwanted links](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25144/unwanted-media-library-urls-in-posts) and records in the posts table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make WLW upload images directly via FTP, you can set this up in settings of connection to your blog.

However as long time WLW user myself I would strongly suggest you to try and make sense of media management in WP, even if it seems excessive at moment (it did to me for a long time). Down the road you will very likely come to some things that are much easier done with media library, rather than organized bunch of directly uploaded files.

I know this very well myself, because I am facing need to re-organize and import three years worth of media at my blog. :)

PS WLW is fine, but do try writing posts in WP itself. A lot of work went into that part of experience and it is very impressive by now.

Comment: Doesn't it clutter the posts table? I've read (rumors?) that WordPress is having serious performance problems once going over 10k records.

Comment: @Bart WordPress is essentially **made** to manage posts. There is absolutely no issue with large amount of posts, other than normal scalability (you need hosting fitting your needs, as with anything).