# Disable Attachment Page Except for Category

Tags: functions, redirect, attachments

I'm looking for a solution similar to [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237762/disable-attachment-pages-completely), except I want to keep attachment pages for attachments in a specific category.

I tried adding the below function, but it's still redirecting all of them:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'test_attachment_redirect', 10 );
function test_attachment_redirect() {
    if( is_attachment() && !is_category('keep')) {
        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_queried_object_id() );
        wp_redirect( $url, 301 );
    }
    return;
}
```

For context, my attachments do have categories with this function:

```
function add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

Comment: attachments don't have categories, it is the posts they're attached to that have the category, for this reason testing the attachment ID for the presence of a category, or using functions that operate on the main loop such as `is_category` will never work for this. Also keeping in mind that an attachment can appear in a post in that category, but not be attached, since attachments can be used in multiple places, but can only have 1 parent post. What's the problem that doing this solves for you? Perhaps there are alternatives that can be suggested you are unaware of

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question to give a little more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `is_category` does not do what you thought it does. `is_category( 'keep' )` tests that the current page is a category archive for the category `keep`, it does not check if the current attachment/post is in the `keep` category.

The official WordPress developers docs for `is_category` start with:

> Determines whether the query is for an existing category archive page.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/

Instead, what you want is to check if the current post has a category assigned, aka `has_category`:

> `has_category( string|int|array $category = '', int|WP_Post $post = null ): bool`
>
> Checks if the current post has any of given category.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_category/

Comment: `has_category` worked, thanks!